# How to transcode EUC-JP to Unicode in a way that can be displayed to the user?

Tags: java, unicode, transcoding

Hello I'm building a simple app for android which allows the user to look up a [kanji](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Kanji) and see its "parts".
To do that I'm reading from a [data file](ftp://ftp.monash.edu.au/pub/nihongo/kradfile.gz) which I found on [this](http://www.csse.monash.edu.au/~jwb/kradinf.html) website and contains the parts of kanji I need to display.

The problem is that its not encoded in unicode and I'm yet to find a program that can display the contents of the file properly. I'm not entirely sure what the encoding is but I suspect it to be `CP932`.

How can I transcode the file to something that can be displayed to the user (and manipulated by java)?

Here is a sample from the contents:

```
±ú : Ñá
±û : ¥Î °ì Âç ÑÌ
±ü : Âç ÊÆ ÑÄ
±ý : ²¦ Ð¦ ×Æ
±þ : ¿´ Öø
²¡ : ¡Ã Æü Ù© ÅÄ
²¢ : ²¦ Æü
²£ : ¡Ã ²« ÅÄ Æó Æü ¥Ï ÌÚ ×°
²¤ : ·ç Ò¹ ¥Î Ð¦
²¥ : ¥Î Ð¦ Ò¹ ÝÕ ÑÜ Ëô
²¦ : ²¦
²§ : ±© ¥Ï ÑÒ ÒÓ
²¨ : ½é Âç ÊÆ ÑÄ ÈÐ
²© : ¾° Ä» ÑÌ Û¿
²ª : Ä» Ò¹ Û¿ ¥Î Ð¦
²« : ²« ÅÄ ¥Ï
²¬ : Öõ ÑÄ °ì »³ ²¬
²­ : ¡Ã ½Á ¸ý
²® : ²Ð ÈÈ çè
²¯ : ²» ²½ ¿´ Æü Î©
²° : »ê ÅÚ ÒÓ Õù
²± : ²» ¿´ Æü Ë» Î©
²² : ²» ·î ¿´ Æü Î©
²³ : ÌÚ ÍÑ ¥Þ
²´ : µí ÅÚ
²µ : ²µ
²¶ : ²µ ²½ Âç ±â
```

Answer (score 1, accepted):

The file is encoded in [EUC-JP](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Extended_Unix_Code#EUC-JP) (not Shift-JIS or CP932). You can either convert the file to a UTF offline with a tool like [iconv](http://www.fileformat.info/tip/linux/iconv.htm), or convert it online by specifying the charset when you create an [`InputStreamReader`](http://developer.android.com/reference/java/io/InputStreamReader.html) to read the file.